# Continue on exception and go to next statement python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a big block of code and whenever I hit an exception I want to ignore it and proceed to next line. Is that possible in python? I want something like-

```
try:
   #some code here
   #see an exception, ignore, continue to next line
   #more code
   #any more code , ignore and march on through rest of block
except:
   pass
```

Comment: yeah: wrap a `try/except` around every line. But it's not very useful... say if a line defines `a` and you get an exception there, `a` is not defined. next line uses `a`: you get an exception again... and so on.

Comment: Python2 or Python3?

Comment: Which python version are you using? It matters in this case

Comment: What's *in* that big block of code? Just steamrolling over the errors seems likely to lead to more problems than it solves. But there's always [`fuckit`](https://github.com/ajalt/fuckitpy).

Comment: I am using Python 2.  I thought of wrapping try/except but is there any other way

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your comment can almost be flagged for abuse :P

Comment: @Illusionist eh I didn't name it!

Comment: @OP please give some context, *why* is that a think you think you want to do?

Comment: I just want to know if it can be done and thanks for the link lol. Ive sometimes come across buggy code and I want to run it and see how badly broken it is before fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in this way, the try-except must around each line, once the line throws exception, it will go to the exception statement and then go to next line. You'd better print/log the exception line.

```
for line in inputs:
    try:
        # your code here
    except Exception as e:
        # log your exception here
```